# Are spacecraft electronic systems built in a modular way that allows astronauts to switch identical cards in case of damage?

Tags: design, space

In *Mars* episode 1, the astronauts find a damaged electronic card in a system. They decide to replace it by another card used by another system and that is supposedly identical to the damaged one. It suggests that the electronic is designed in a modular way and that the different systems use a set of generic cards to carry out their task.

Is it possible to build such a system in a way that makes it viable in space (reliable, with a reasonable amount of spare and complexity)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Design for repair is usually done with the final environment in mind.

In avionics and the military, they use the term LRU, Line Replaceable Unit, for what a 'front line' repair is expected to do. These usually come down to a rack mounted module of several litres, that plugs into a rack. Here, rapid repair by technicians with limited training, in field conditions, is paramount. 'Second line' repair, done back at base, involves opening the modules and doing board swaps. Repair at the component level would be sent back to the manufacturer. I am not so much worried about the details, but the fact that a maintenance and repair strategy has been designed in from the start, and is part of the procurement specification of the equipment.

If a deep space mission was being planned, part of the environment to consider would be that no new gear could be brought up, that the technicians were limited in their electronic skills, but that conditions were clean, and that time to repair probably was not of the essence, especially as the systems themselves would be duplicated. This means that board swap would probably be considered to be the primary repair strategy. To minimise the number of spares carried, this would require common boards wherever possible, and this would be demanded of all suppliers of systems to the project.

Spares would be carried. Cannibalising a system to get a board would be possible, but an option of last resort. If the story had them doing this, then they had already suffered a lot of failures, and used their spares.

Comment: Thank you for all the details, "LRU" led me to interesting articles about this.

Comment: In some industrial systems there may be many common parts. For example.. Data Acquisition modules (we called them DAQs) were common and there were only 2 variants. But 20 were used in one machine. This meant we could swap DAQs around and see if the fault moved. This confirmed the DAQ was faulty or if the fault was in the more specialist equipment. Then the appropriate item could be replaced or taken for repair.

Comment: Just a precision: LRU stands for "Line-replacable unit". In airborne computers they are now seeking to develop a single type of hardware LRU with specific softwares, called IMA (Integrated Modular Avionics). It began with Airbus A380. An overview of IMA can be found here : http://www.scarlettproject.eu/about/Project_Overview.pdf

Comment: @zeqL you're right, it's line replaceable

Answer (score 3):

The need to replace items in space due to wearout is what limits humans to remain in our solar system.
I don't know how we can build systems durable for 100,000 years, thus the spacecraft must take along equipment to manufacture new ball bearings for the fans in the AirConditioning system; at some point the humans need the skills to produce yet another ball-bearing-manufacturing machine.